# Inequality $(x^{-1}+\tan^{-1}x - \tanh^{-1}x )(\tan^{-1}x +\tanh^{-1}x )<2$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Can not figure out how to prove the inequality
$$(x^{-1}+\tan^{-1}x - \tanh^{-1}x )(\tan^{-1}x +\tanh^{-1}x )<2$$
over its domain.

Given the symmetry, it suffices to prove the inequality for $x\in (0,1)$. And, it is straightforward to verify that the limit of the LHS at $x=0$ is $2$. But the standard method to examine its first few derivatives does not appear to work, for it is not obvious to determine their signs due to the complex functional forms of the derivatives.

It is observed that the inequality around $x=0$ is very tight, which can be seen from the leading term $\frac{14}{15}x^4$ of its Taylor expansion.

Comment: Have you tried putting $$\tanh^{-1}x = \frac1{2}\,\log\Big(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\Big) \qquad \text{and} \qquad \tan^{-1} x = \frac1{2i}\,\log\Big(\frac{1+ix}{1-ix}\Big)?$$

Comment: Taylor expansion shows it is strictly less than $2$ $$2-\frac{14 x^4}{15}-\frac{194 x^8}{315}-\frac{63814 x^{12}}{135135}-\frac{296966 x^{16}}{765765}-\frac{3444218 x^{20}}{10392525}+O\left(x^{21}\right)$$

Comment: @Raffaele - that’s reassuring from the series; interesting to note that it is in $x^{4k}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us prove that, for all $x$ in $(0, 1)$,
$$\frac{2}{\arctan x + \operatorname{arctanh} x} - \frac{1}{x} - \arctan x + \operatorname{arctanh} x \ge 0. \tag{1}$$
Denote LHS by $f(x)$. We have (the proof is given at the end)
$$f'(x) = -\frac{4}{(\arctan x + \operatorname{arctanh} x)^2(1-x^4)}  + \frac{1+x^4}{x^2(1-x^4)}\ge 0, \quad \forall x\in (0, 1). \tag{2}$$
Also, $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0$ (apply L'Hopital rule). Thus, we have $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$ in $(0, 1)$.

We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of (2)*: It suffices to prove that
$$\arctan x + \operatorname{arctanh} x - \frac{2x}{\sqrt{1+x^4}} \ge 0, \quad \forall x \in (0, 1).$$
Denote LHS by $g(x)$. We have, for all $x$ in $(0, 1)$,
$$g'(x) = \frac{2}{1-x^4} - \frac{2(1-x^4)}{(1+x^4)^{3/2}} \ge 0.$$
Also, $g(0) = 0$. Thus, $g(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$ in $(0, 1)$.